# How to store temporary data on server and share to many users

Tags: java, servlets, store, temporary

I'm developing an online chess game by Servlet and MySQL. And my program have mutil match (2 players unit).

Now I want to store each Match's data (String) on server and every player do his turn, this Match's data will be updated.

What the best solution to store this temporary data?

Comment: You say you are using MySQL, why isn't that the answer?

Comment: Match's data changed every user do his turn, therefore it can be change every second. If I use database to store this data, I will connect to database every second. Is it best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with hitting a database every second as long as you are using a connection pool. Use the database. If you're really afraid of that, use memcache or reddis.

Mysql can handle hundreds of queries a second on a small server.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/164980/how-many-selects-per-second-can-a-mysql-server-run

Those are selects... but they're talking thousands. If you're just updating a row for the state of a chess game, that's a very simple write operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a new bee with memcache or reddis but they are really what I need.